# Converting implied volatilities into digital option prices

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility, digital

I have Black and Scholes (1973) implied volatilities computed and I would like to convert these IVs to digital option prices using a Black and Scholes type of formula, I can't find a formula to do this. How can I convert IVs to digital option prices?

Comment: Assuming you have a vol surface, does https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68264/54838 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can just assume a flat vol Black Scholes world. In this case, using the usual BS notation, the fair price of the cash or nothing option is e^(−rt)*N(d2) which is the [discounted probability](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154432/109107) of the option expiring in the money.

Demonstrating this in [Julia](https://julialang.org/), you can define this as follows (call price will be needed later).

```
using Distributions
function BSM(S,K,t,rf,d,σ, cp_flag)
    d1 = ( log(S/K) + (rf - d + 1/2*σ^2)*t ) / (σ*sqrt(t))
    d2 = d1 - σ*sqrt(t)
    value  = cp_flag*exp(-d*t)S*N(cp_flag*d1) - exp(-rf*t)*cp_flag*K*N(cp_flag*d2)
  return value, exp(-r*t)*N(cp_flag*d2)
end
```

Looking at an example from Bloomberg,

[image]

we can compute the following result

```
# inputs 
s,k , t, σ, r, d  = 19280.78, 19280.78, 1, 0.2471, -0.00006, 0.02061
#result 
res = BSM(s,k,t,log(1+r*t)/t,log(1+d*t)/t,σ, 1)
println("Digital Value per unit = $(round(res[2],digits = 5))")
```

[image]

Bloomberg does not seem to use a call spread in OVME which is why it is so close. Bloomberg does use a call spread in [OVML (FX)](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154955/109107) though. If you were to do this yourself, things get a bit more involved. For example, setting strikes at ± =  ±1/2.

The gif shows this with unrealistic spreads and shifts to make the distinction clear. The actual values however are computed accurately and would match OVML. You can read some details [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68264/54838).

[image]

We need to define a few more things to set this up:

- compute the spread (frequently 1% is used, but ideally it is expiry and vol dependent)

```
function spread(K,shift)
        lower_K = K*(1-shift/2)
        upper_K = K*(1+shift/2)
        spread  = upper_K-lower_K
        return lower_K, upper_K, spread
    end
spr = spread(k,0.01)
val = ("Lower","Upper","Spread")
k = Dict(zip(val,spr))
```

- Compute the notional adjustment needed to get the desired payoff (The spread * Notional equals the sum of payoffs in the spread scenario - this needs to be adjust to get the desired notional).

```
    function notional(desiredPayoff,spread)
        scale = desiredPayoff/(spread*desiredPayoff)
        return scale*desiredPayoff
    end
```

- Fetch the IV for the two strikes (for simplicity I just assume 3 different scenarios: flat, higher vol for lower strike (OTM Put Skew), higher upper strike (OTM Call Skew).

```
σ = Dict("Lower" =>  [0.2471,0.2473,0.2470], "Upper" =>  [0.2471,0.2470,0.2473] )
```

- compute value (in percent of underlying):

```
scenario = ["Flat", "OTM Put Skew", "OTM Call Skew"]
res = ["Digital Value per unit ($(scenario[i])) = $((BSM(s,k["Lower"],t, log(1+r*t)/t,log(1+d*t)/t,σ["Lower"][i],1)[1] - BSM(s,k["Upper"],t, log(1+r*t)/t,log(1+d*t)/t,σ["Upper"][i],1)[1])*notional(s,spr[3])/s)" for i in 1:1:3 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in AKdemy's comment and link, you also need the vanilla IV slope in addition to the level.

Digital put price is
$$
\partial_K P(S_t,K) = \partial_K P_{BS}(S_t,K,I(S_t,K)) + \partial_I P_{BS}(S_t,K,I(S_t,K)) \, \partial_K I(S_t,K)
$$